# Should we use MediatR + Services + Repositories?

Tags: service, repository-pattern, mediatr

We're using MediatR and inside the Handlers we directly call the Repositories to get/add/delete data. Should we always create a Service that calls the Repositories instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use repository in handlers, you don't need to create another layer (service).

MediatR

1.) Get, GetAll ,GetByCondition ... (all get calls)

```
Controller -> Queries (Queries layer) -> Repository
```

2.) Add/Update/Delete

```
Controller -> CommandHandlers (handlers layer) -> Repository
```